# htacess: triple rewrite HTTPS + no-WWW + no-.html

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, no-www

I am trying to write a multi rewrite function in htacess.

- change http into httpS
- remove www
- remove .html

It should handle all the cases:
http://www.example.com/about.html
should be rewritten as
http S://example.com/about

But of course if there is only one item to rewrite it should work too:
http://example.com/about
should be rewritten as
http S://example.com/about

Here is my code (https and no-WWW work but the no-.html which is commented does not work).
Please note that when rewriting you need to use the previously rewrited URL and not what the user typed into his address bar otherwise the rule will overwrite the change that another rule did.

```
RewriteEngine on

#strip the www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

#remove .html if any
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
#RewriteRule ^(([^/]*/)*[^/.]+)$ /$1.html [L]

#switch to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

# Disable the server signature
ServerSignature Off
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

#strip the www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

#switch to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

#remove .html if any
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

# Disable the server signature
ServerSignature Off
```